# Pyaudio: Audio playback sounds horrible when using WASAPI driver

Tags: python, pyaudio

When I select WASAPI as my host API, any wav file I play sounds garbled.  If I choose MME, it sounds fine.

If I play the same wav file with Audacity and choose WASAPI as the host, this sounds fine as well.
Also, I can record audio just fine using the WASAPI API.

```
import pyaudio
import wave

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

wf = wave.open('test.wav', 'rb')

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output_device_index=41,
                output=True)

data = wf.readframes(1024)

while len(data) > 0:
  stream.write(data)
  data = wf.readframes(1024)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
```

Comment: Is your question "Why is sound garbled when I select WASAPI as the host?"?

Comment: Yes, that is the question.